# リストをitemgetterしているはずなのに何故かtupleになっている

Tags: python, python3

下記は例になりますが、このようなコードで何故かtupleになってしまいます。
原因がわかりません。
些細な質問になりますが、ご教授をよろしくお願いいたします。

```
from operator import itemgetter

List1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]

for i, row in enumerate(List1):
  save = []
  print(type(row)) # <- <class 'list'>
  save = itemgetter(0,2)(row)
  print(type(save)) # <- <class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「何故かtupleになってしまいます。」とのことですが、ドキュメントの説明にある通りかと思います。

[operator.itemgetter(*items)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

> `operator.itemgetter(item)`
> `operator.itemgetter(*items)`
> 演算対象からその [_*getitem*_()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/operator.html#operator.__getitem__) メソッドを使って item を取得する呼び出し可能なオブジェクトを返します。 二つ以上のアイテムを要求された場合には、アイテムのタプルを返します。

質問のコードの場合は`['a', 'b', 'c']`の0番目と2番目の要素であるaとcが`('a', 'c')`として取得されます。同様に `['x', 'y', 'z']`の0番目と2番目の要素であるxとzが`('x', 'z')`として取得されます。